# Cohomology ring of $\mathbb RP^n$ with integral coefficient.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I know cup product structure on $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)= \mathbb{Z}_2[\alpha]/(\alpha^{n+1})$. How to get  $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$ from this? I have two cochain complexes for two coefficient rings.

Now my question is what will be the induced map between these two cochain complexes and what will be  $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @Thomas, is universal coefficients theorem really telling anything about multiplication in cohomology?

Comment: This is more a general remark, but unless you're in an exceptional situation, I doubt that you can recover integral cohomology from mod 2 cohomology in any way. You just kill too much information.

Answer (score 4):

I think, $H^*(\mathbb RP^{2n+1})=\mathbb Z[\alpha,\beta]/(2\alpha,\alpha^{n+1},\alpha\beta,\beta^2)$, where $\alpha$ has degree $2$ and $\beta$ has degree $2n+1$.

You can see it when you write down spectral sequence for $S^1$-fibration $\mathbb RP^{2n+1}\to\mathbb CP^n$ and look on multiplicative structure (as you doing for calculating ring $H^*(\mathbb CP^{n})$).

And for odd dimension, $H^*(\mathbb RP^{2n})=\mathbb Z[\alpha]/(2\alpha,\alpha^{n+1})$, where $\alpha$ has degree $2$. It makes cleare when you consider inclusion $\mathbb RP^{2n}\to\mathbb RP^{2n+1}$.

EDIT: this spectral sequence just shows that when you project $\mathbb RP^{2n+1}\to\mathbb CP^n$, the pullback maps $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_2$ in cohomology are surjections, and ring structure is induced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....I don't think I have understood it  clearly....I need some time to think over your solution...

Comment: @Ripan, see the last edit. maybe, my explanation is not pure, but this fact is really easy to understand

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer in the odd case in the top dimension. For example, the degree 1 cohomology of $RP^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. (And it doesn't give the right answer in degree 0 regardless.)

Comment: @John, i think now i finally fix it

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128712/integral-cohomology-ring-of-real-projective-space), the answer to which is given in a comment. See also [this website](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_real_projective_space), which was the first thing I found when I searched for "cohomology of projective space".