# To Understand The Cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to understand the Cohomology ring structure of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients using the Coholomogy ring of of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. The approach seems to be looking at the Ring map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, it induces a group homomorphism $C^k(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow C^k(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\forall k\geq 0$, This will induce maps between the Cohomology groups, which in turn will give us that for $k$ even, $H^k(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^K(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ becomes isomorphic (Using Naturality which I don't understand much).

Please don't flag it as a duplicate, I have seen the other answers on this site. I don't know Spectral Sequences. Also I am struggling to understand these proofs rigorously. If someone can explain the mentioned part above and if possible sketch the rest of the calculation of $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128712/integral-cohomology-ring-of-real-projective-space/2318904 makes no use of spectral sequences. What parts of the answers there are confusing?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I am having trouble to prove that the ring homomorphism mentioned on the first paragraph in the answer is injective.

Comment: You still need to give more information. Do you know cellular homology? The universal coefficient theorem?

Comment: Yeah I do know both of them. Not so much comfortable with Naturality though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with one cell in each dimension up to $n$, then the cellular chain complex looks like this:
$$
... \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}.
$$
If you choose your favorite ring $R$ and apply $\text{Hom}(-, R)$, you will get the cellular cochain complex with coefficients in $R$; the multiplication by 2 map in the old chain complex becomes the multiplication by 2 map $R \to R$ in the new cochain complex, and the same for the zero map. Also, if you have a ring map $f: R \to S$, it will induce a map on cellular cochain complexes. (Why? A cochain with coefficients in $R$ is a map $C_i \to R$, so just compose with $f$ to get a map $C_i \to R \to S$.) In particular, if you apply this to the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{F}_2$, you will get a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\cdots & \xleftarrow{2} &\mathbb{Z} & \xleftarrow{0} & \mathbb{Z} & \xleftarrow{2} & \mathbb{Z} & \xleftarrow{0} & \mathbb{Z} \\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow \\
\cdots & \xleftarrow{0} & \mathbb{F}_2 & \xleftarrow{0} & \mathbb{F}_2 & \xleftarrow{0} & \mathbb{F}_2 & \xleftarrow{0} & \mathbb{F}_2
\end{array}
$$
Each vertical map is the quotient map. Now take cohomology of these chain complexes:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\cdots & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/2 & 0 & \mathbb{Z} \\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow \\
\cdots & \mathbb{F}_2 & \mathbb{F}_2 & \mathbb{F}_2 & \mathbb{F}_2
\end{array}
$$
(I'm thinking of the terms in the top row as abelian groups, the terms in the bottom row as vector spaces over the field with 2 elements; hence the different notation for the same groups.) You can check that the vertical map in each even dimension is an isomorphism: use the fact that in the map of cochain complexes, the vertical maps were reduction mod 2, and that in the integral cohomology in dimension $2r$ (for any $r>0)$, the element $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ represents the nonzero cohomology class.